# Setting Facebook og:image in ExactTarget email using Social Forward

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-opengraph, exacttarget

I'm trying to define the thumbnail I want to show up when a user shares an email via Facebook with ExactTarget.

HTML tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Relevant head code:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://image.mail-
rushcard.com/lib/fef91374776306/i/2/a53bc403-2.jpg"/>
```

This does nothing. No matter what I try, Facebook is just grabbing the first image in the email (a full-width header) and using it as the thumbnail.

What am I missing? Do I need to have the thumbnail image actually in the email ? or can I just link to it with the header meta tags?

I've tried putting the thumbnail image in the email content, and it still did not work.

The OG Debugger is telling me "The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."

Comment: What do you mean by sharing an email? You mean a web page?

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [Marketing-Cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [AMPScript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.